# Ruby - mysql2 driver changing encoding / various utf-8 issues

Tags: mysql, ruby, encoding, utf-8, mysql2

I have an API running on Sinatra.  It queries a mysql databases, and returns data in json or xml format.  I'm having a problem with unicode data.  If I query the production database from the console, I'll get data correctly:

```
persönlichen
```

However, in my API results (or if I were to query the database in irb using the mysql2 gem), I get this:

```
persÃ¶nlichen
```

Everything works swimmingly on my development box, which is confounding my efforts to solve the problem.

I have done everything I can to make sure that the database is utf-8 only (encodings, collations, client and server character sets are all utf-8).  I'm using the mysql2 driver, which supposedly forces everything to utf-8.  I'm setting :encoding => 'UTF8' on my active record connection.

What am I missing?

Comment: What about the invididual tables / columns ? Are those utf8 too ?

Comment: How about you promote your development machine to production duty? :-) Are all the versions of drivers and gems in the production and development systems in sync?

Comment: All of the columns are collated as utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to nail the problem down - the data wasn't encoded correctly in the database.  I was populating my database using a sql dump file - I added this to the top, and everything worked great:

```
set names utf8;
create database if not exists `my_db_name` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```